# Magento - Upgrade extension folder structure for version 1.9+ (1.7 - 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, extensions

Considering my extension name - `myextensionfolder`, the current structure is compatible to CE Magento versions `1.7, 1.8, 1.8.1`

```
app/code/community/myextensionfolder

app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/myextensionfolder
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/myextensionfolder
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/myextensionfolder
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/myextensionfolder

skin/frontend/default/default/css/myextensionfolder
skin/frontend/default/default/images/myextensionfolder
skin/frontend/default/default/js/myextensionfolder
```

After installing it for version `1.9`, admin end works as expected but does not work for frontend(only). Though it works by replacing `app/design` and `skin/frontend` folders as shown below.

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template

skin/frontend/rwd/default/css
skin/frontend/rwd/default/js
skin/frontend/rwd/default/images
```

If I put the files in default `rwd` theme then it does not reflect anything on frontend for ver `1.7-1.8`

What should be the correct approach to modify my extension folder structure to make it compatible till version `1.9+` so that user can install it for version `1.7 - 1.9.2.1`

P.S. - The question is to **alter extension folder structure** to make it compatible till version 1.9+ and **NOT** to simply upgrade Magento Community Edition version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to emphasise that you are wrong with the assessment of default location of magento extensions or modules.

The default location for frontend is `base/default` and for admin, default location is `default\default`. So when you write an an extension, the best practices says, you should use following locations.

```
app/code/community/myextensionfolder

app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/myextensionfolder
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/myextensionfolder
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/myextensionfolder
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/myextensionfolder

skin/frontend/base/default/css/myextensionfolder
skin/frontend/base/default/images/myextensionfolder
skin/frontend/base/default/js/myextensionfolder
```

The reason for this, Magento uses a fallback mechanism in the case of `package\theme`. That is it it will loop over different package\theme directory (it depends upon the configuration we have on the `system > admin > design` section) and if it can't find a file, then finally it will come to the parent package\theme directory. For frontend, this parent package\theme directory is `base\default` and for admin section, it is `default\default`

### EDIT

For your custom works or for custom modules, you should always use the current package\theme. Modules should also reside under `local` codepool.

Comment: Agree to your point, and so when user has custom theme, the folders have to manually placed under relevant theme ? Also does the best practice advises to use `base/default` location for only extension OR for custom module as well ?

Comment: @Vikram for custom module it should be in the current theme location. that is the best practice for `local` modules

Comment: Conclusion: For custom modules, path should be current theme i.e (`default/default` or `custompackage/customtheme`) and for extensions it should always be `base/default`. Pls correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: @Vikram you are in the right path. Kudos

Comment: @Vikram I've edited answer and added it too. Please accept any one of the answer, if it cleared your confusions

Answer (score 0):

You can place your theme files in `base/default` theme.

If your place your extension theme files in base theme it'll work for both default and RWD theme.

i.e.,

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout
app/design/frontend/bsae/default/template

skin/frontend/base/default/css
skin/frontend/base/default/js
skin/frontend/base/default/images
```

Comment: Why `base/default` and not `default./default` ? Is this the correct approach to make it work for all the versions ranging from 1.7-1.9 ?

Comment: Check this link http://blog.belvg.com/magento-fallback-configuration-default-and-specific-themes-packages-design-exceptions-temporary-theme-configuration.html.

Because the fallback  'll work like that, if any files are not present in our theme it'll look the default in the current package. If the file is not present in current package/default theme. it'll look into the base default theme.

So If any one use third party theme with separate package name, our extension theme files will not work. So always use base/default for custom extension.